# "Last Mobile Install Reported" has no android install event

Tags: android

I develop an app on both ios and android platform using sdk 3.5 ,
Last Mobile Install Reported only display ios event, android event is missing.

like this:

/////

Last Mobile Install Reported
iOS：    2013年11月21日 14:51

```
More details on reported events
```

////

protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

```
    String AppId = this.getString(R.string.app_id);
    com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, AppId);
```

}

But when I click "More details on reported events", I can see android login event.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?